# Which is the Correct Way to Use std::cin.get()

Tags: c++

After years of C++ programming, I never dug into the differences of these two usages of `std::cin.get()` and do not understand which of these two is the correct way for retrieving a `char`.

```
char character;
std::cin.get(character);
```

vs

```
char character;
character = std::cin.get();
```

Comment: What about looking that up in the [reference doucumentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) (Hint: the return types are different)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char character;
character = std::cin.get();
```

is not ideal because `std::cin.get()` returns `int`, this is to allow you to check for end of file or other error by testing `ch`

```
int ch = std::cin.get();
if (ch != EOF)
{
    ...
}
```

The alternative method tests `cin` itself for end of file or error

```
char ch;
if (std::cin.get(ch))
{
    ...
}
```

As far as I can see, the difference between these two is just a matter of style, although the second method is overloaded on types `unsigned char` and `signed char` should that be important to you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was told to check the references, but it wasn't apparent to me how their real-world applications would differ.  This helps.